# Does robot traffic visiting your website have any advantages?

Tags: web-crawlers, traffic

What are the advantages of having bot traffic on your website?

Will it raise your SEO ranking on Google?

Real visitors would raise awareness of your product and site, but the visitors I'm seeing appear to be robots that only view the pages.

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific? What "bots" are you talking about? Obviously search engine bots allow your site to get indexed - so yes, it is mandatory for any SEO ranking at all for these bots to visit your site!?

Comment: I guess I can thank the person who edited my post for creating the confusion. Originally my post mentioned nothing about "bots". It just simply referred to viewers who were acting like robots and clicking on my pages. Nothing to do with google bots indexing my sites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robot traffic **does not affect page rank**. Whilst robots can & may index your website, the sheer volume of robots hitting your website does not play any role whatsoever in affecting your page rank, the driving force behind Google's organic search traffic algorithm.

Brian Dean shared a very, very comprehensive list of factors which influence this which can be found here:

[Backlinko - Google Ranking Factors](http://backlinko.com/google-ranking-factors)

A lot of what he references are updates directly from [Matt Cutts](https://twitter.com/mattcutts) who leads the web spam team at Google, and works with the search quality team on search engine optimization issues.

One thing I personally found out the hard way is that SEO is not a destination, but quite literally a life-long (or at least for the duration of your employment) journey. You'll never really be finished with it & there are constant updates in the field which will require you to stay on top of things.

Comment: Good answer, but it ought to me made clear that for a search engine to be able to rank your site, you *do* need to allow it access.